# SQL Multiple count columns with multiple conditionS

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to gather some basic statistics from a table "Data_Table" that gets updated on a daily basis. Each row represents a case, which can be opened/closed/cancelled by an operator with a unique ID. I want to be able to show the count for the actions that each operator did the previous day. So getting from Data_Table to Ideal table.

### Data_Table

```
|  LOCATION |   DATE   | REFERENCE | OPENED_ID | CLOSED_ID | CANCELLED_ID  |
|    NYC    | 20180102 |  123451   |    123    |    234    |      0        |
|    TEX    | 20180102 |  123452   |    345    |    123    |      0        |
|    NYC    | 20180102 |  123453   |    345    |     0     |     123       |
|    TEX    | 20180102 |  123453   |    234    |     0     |     123       |
```

---

### Ideal Table

```
|  LOCATION |   DATE   | USER_ID | OPEN | CLOSED | CANCELLED  |
|    NYC    | 20180102 |  123    |  1   |   0    |     1      |  
|    NYC    | 20180102 |  234    |  0   |   1    |     0      |
|    NYC    | 20180102 |  345    |  1   |   0    |     0      |
|    TEX    | 20180102 |  123    |  0   |   1    |     1      |
|    TEX    | 20180102 |  234    |  1   |   0    |     0      |
|    TEX    | 20180102 |  345    |  1   |   0    |     0      |
```

User 123 opened 1 case and cancelled 1 case in location NYC on date 20180102...etc.

I have made a few small queries for each action in each site that looks like this:

```
SELECT LOCATION, DATE, OPENED_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT [DATA_TABLE].REFERENCE)
FROM [DATA_TABLE]
WHERE DATE = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-1)
AND LOCATION = 'NYC'
AND OPENED_ID in (SELECT NYC FROM [OP_ID_TABLE]WHERE [DATE FINISH] > GETDATE() )
GROUP BY OPENED_ID, LOCATION, DATE
ORDER BY LOCATION
```

And then repeat this query for each location for each operator action. After which I do some messy vlookups in excel to organise it into the Ideal table format, which on a daily basis is ..not ideal.

I've tried to make some sum functions but haven't had any luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unpivot and re-aggregate.  One method uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select location, date, user_id,
       sum(opened) as opens, sum(closed) as closes, sum(cancelled) as cancels
from ((select location, date, opened_id as user_id, 1 as opened, 0 as closed, 0 as cancelled
       from t
      ) union all
      (select location, date, closed_id as user_id, 0 as opened, 1 as closed, 0 as cancelled
       from t
      ) union all
      (select location, date, cancelled_id as user_id, 0 as opened, 0 as closed, 1 as cancelled
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by location, date, user_id;
```

There are other methods for doing these operations, depending on the database. However, this is ANSI-standard syntax.